# MDX: How to go back 1 year-to-date while taking leap year into consideration?

Tags: mdx, leap-year

Trying to come up with a query that will give me the set of dates going back 365 days from today (and in leap years past feb, 366 days).

Here's what I got so far:

`Select [Measures].[Revenue] on 0,
non empty {[Trans Date].[Year - Week - Date].[Date], PARALLELPERIOD([Trans Date].[Year - Week - Date].[Year], 1,[Trans Date].[Year - Week - Date]) }on 1
from Cube`

This but this goes back to the beginning of "time". I just need it to go back 365 (or 366 of leap year.)

Thought of using Lag, but not quite sure ho it would fit in this scheme.
Anyone have any advice on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm going to reformat your query for readability.

```
SELECT [Measures].[Revenue] ON 0,
       NON EMPTY 
       {
         [Trans Date].[Year - Week - Date].[Date],
         PARALLELPERIOD([Trans Date].[Year - Week - Date].[Year],
                        1,
                        [Trans Date].[Year - Week - Date])
       } ON 1
FROM Cube
```

What you have here is a set of the entire `Date` level (`[Trans Date].[Year - Week - Date].[Date]`), and additionally a single member from that dimension (the result of the `PARALLELPERIOD` call).

What you want is a range of members, which is accomplished with the [range operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146001.aspx) `:`. For example,

```
NON EMPTY
{
  PARALLELPERIOD([Trans Date].[Year - Week - Date].[Year],
                 1,
                 [Trans Date].[Year - Week - Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER)
  :
  [Trans Date].[Year - Week - Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER
} ON 1
```

<3

Comment: Your example doesn't account for leap years.

Comment: This is true; `PARALLELPERIOD` only returns a member under the parallel ancestor with the same ordinal as the given member. If there isn't some way of working with the date value of a member directly through MDX, it may be necessary to generate numeric member properties (e.g., referring to the ordinal of the previous year's member for this date) programmatically, to assist this process.